# What would be the fold expression in Vim to fold unittests when using D?

Tags: vim, editor, d, folding

I've been using D a lot recently and using Vim as an editor. I deal with code that has a lot of inline unit tests and i want to fold these so i can only see code. What would the fold expression in Vim need to be to fold these unit tests automatically?

Here is an example of what they look like in the D code:

```
T getUnixTime(T, A...)(A args)
{
    return to!T(SysTime(DateTime(args)).toUnixTime());
}

unittest
{
    assert(getUnixTime!string(2013, 7, 18, 14, 49, 43) == "1374155383");
    assert(getUnixTime!uint(2071, 12, 5, 12, 9, 5) == 3216542945);
}
```

I would like this to look like:

```
T getUnixTime(T, A...)(A args)
{
    return to!T(SysTime(DateTime(args)).toUnixTime());
}

+--  5 lines: unittest----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: None. I've absolutely no idea where to begin! Hence me asking for help on a programmers Q&A site. You any idea?

Comment: It's just that I've heard that "send me the code" style questions are somewhat frowned upon on Stackoverflow. Can't help you, but there's an in-depth tutorial on fold expressions in [LVtHW](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html) and many, many further hints in [the other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vim]+foldexpr) about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a "foldexpression" or for a "fold command"?

Supposing your cursor is on `unittest`, you can do

```
zf/{/e
```

to create a fold.

Make it a mapping for more speed.

Comment: I would assume a foldexpression. The following is what I mostly use as a modline but it's inadequate for OP's purpose `vim:fdc=3:fdm=expr:fde=getline(v\:lnum)=~'\unittest'?'>1'\:'1'`. Please show us how it's done :).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late reply. I was looking for the same functionality, and eventually came up with this:

```
set foldexpr=DlangUnitTestFold(v:lnum)

" If the line matches `unittest {`, increase the indentation.
" Keep the indentation level steady until we encounter a line
" that only matches `}`: if so, decrease the indentation.

function! DlangUnitTestFold(lnum)
  if getline(a:lnum) =~ '^\s*unittest\s{\s*$'
    return "a1"
  elseif getline(a:lnum) =~ '^\s*}\s*$'
    return "s1"
  else
    return "="
  endif
endfunction
```

Not sure if it's all too hacky, but it works for me :)

**Edit**: Ideally, you'd place the first line in a setlocal, e.g.:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.d setlocal foldexpr=DlangUnitTestFold(v:lnum)
```